# How to find the default runner application for a windows file extension in Javascript/Extendscript

Tags: visual-studio-code, adobe, extendscript, winreg

I am creating an extendscript that requires the verification that python is installed on the machine. In order to do this, I want a function that looks somewhat like this:

`function defaultApp(fileExtension) { return defaultAppName; }`

And then check if the default app name is 'python.exe'.
From my understanding (that had gathered from another similar post that implements a solution using the python winreg library), the windows registry should be accessed to get such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a bat file something like this:

```
python --version > d:\p.txt
```

And then to check the content of the txt file. If Python is installed (and configured) you will get info about a version of the Python. If there is no Python you will get empty txt file.

It can be something like this:

```
function check_python() {

    // create the bat file
    var bat_file = File(Folder.temp + "/python_check.bat");
    bat_file.open("w");
    bat_file.write("python --version > %temp%/python_check.txt");
    bat_file.close();

    // check if the bat file was created
    if (!bat_file.exists) {
        alert ("Can't check if Python is installed");
        return false;
    }

    // run the bat file
    bat_file.execute();
    $.sleep(300); 

    // check if the txt file exists
    var check_file = File(Folder.temp + "/python_check.txt");
    if (!check_file.exists) { 
        alert ("Can't check if Python is installed"); 
        bat_file.remove();
        return false;
    }

    // get contents of the txt file
    check_file.open("r");
    var contents = check_file.read();
    check_file.close();

    // check the contents
    if (contents.indexOf("Python 3") != 0) { 
        alert("Python 3 is not found"); 
        bat_file.remove();
        check_file.remove();
        return false;
    }

    // hooray!
    alert("Python is found!")
    bat_file.remove();
    check_file.remove();
    return true;
}

var is_python = check_python();
```

Comment: This is actually a simple but interesting solution that works on all platforms. I am going to use this for now instead of doing it the "ugly way" by checking the win registry or whatnot.

Comment: If you're curious, check my own answer, in which I try to implement a more compact version of your script using a small utility.

Comment: Yep. Your version looks smart. I will use it. Nevertheless both the versions will work on Windows only. MacOS will need another implementation.

Comment: I've never used a Mac before, so I wouldn't know. But I assume the same logic applies.

Comment: Now you have me curious, what other changes would a MacOS implementation entail?

Comment: On MacOS the same logic, indeed. Just a little bit another commands to create and run files. There is no cmd or bat files. Any txt file can be executed if it has some properties (mods) enabled. And there is Apple Script (something alike Visual Basic on Windows) it can be used as well in this case. I'm using MacOS often but I'm not an expert by any stretch.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the information! I might run into this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is inspired by Yuri Khristich's answer. (A more compact version)

```
//@include "utils/$file.jsx";
function ispy()
{
    var ispy,
        cmd = "python --version > %temp%/pycheck.txt",
        chk = File(Folder.temp + "/pycheck.txt").$create(),
        bat = File(Folder.temp + "/pycheck.bat").$create(cmd);
    
    bat.$execute(100);
    ispy = !!chk.$read();
    //cleanup:
    File.remove(bat, chk);
    return ispy;
}

$.writeln(ispy()) //true
```

$read, $create, $execute and File.remove() are not built-in functions. I created them to help declutter my code.